# Git doesnt show commited icon

Tags: git

I've just installed Git latest version on Window 64 bit.

Problems: Git does not show icon (tick symbol with green circle around) showing the files have been committed to git although it is a git repository..[View the picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMxQe.png)

Comment: Is there a `.git` folder? It can be hidden on Windows.

Comment: @Dennis: Yes, Windows hidden it but what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a simple glitch or an update. IDK. But you can see you git commit with the command `git log`. So you can see if they are realy commited and if it's a simple display bug, or another bug. Keep us informed.